# Square matrix notation (orthogonal superscript)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, matrix-equations, orthogonality

I am reading a paper and have a question about notation that I am not familiar with. The expression I need help with is given below. I am unfamiliar with orthogonal superscript following a square matrix.

$$ y = A^{\perp}Bx $$
where $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{\text{m} \times \text{m}}, \ B \in \mathbb{R}^{\text{m} \times \text{n}}, \ x \in \mathbb{R}^{\text{n}}, \ y \in \mathbb{R}^{\text{m}} $

Is $ A^{\perp} $ simply any square matrix (excluding the trivial zero matrix) orthogonal to $A$ (i.e. $ A^{\perp}A=[0] \text{, where } [0]$ is the m$\times$m zero matrix)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It would be helpful to get the context. Did the author not even mention this notation in the previous sections?

Comment: No, not at all. This is an optimization problem where $y$ is used to minimize a cost function

Comment: Probably a system, where $y$ is a vector. My point is that since $A$ is $m\times m$, then $A^{\perp}$ is a countable set. So, your system has $Card(A^{\perp})$ equations. Just a lucky guess, I may be wrong.

Comment: You are correct in that $y$ is a vector. In particular, it is necessary that $y \in \mathbb{R}^m $. I have added this fact to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the paper has answered my question. The notation is as speculated in the original post. In particular, $A^{\perp}$ is a matrix orthogonal to $A$. In other words $ A^{\perp} $ satisfies the following;
$$ A^{\perp}A=0, \ A^{\perp} \neq [0] $$